# Python Passing Variables Between Two Functions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, variables, tkinter

I'm trying to have the first function to open the file and the second function to print the contents of the file. Running into a few errors if someone could help me out the would be great!

```
global strings

def open_file(): 
    file = askopenfile(parent=root,mode ='r', filetypes =[("All files", "*")])
    if file is not None: 
        content = file.read()
    strings = content.splitlines()
    return strings

def run_file(some_content):
    for i in some_content:
        print(bytes(i,"ascii"))
        time.sleep(1)

btn_upload = Button(root, text="UPLOAD",bg='#34495e', fg='white', command = lambda:open_file())
btn_upload.pack()
btn_run = Button(root, text="RUN",bg='#34495e', fg='white', command=lambda:run_file(strings))
btn_run.pack()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put `global strings` inside the `open_file()` function (and indeed in any function that assigns to that name; reading from globals works without `global`).

```
strings = None

def open_file(): 
    global strings 
    # ...

def run_file():
    for i in strings:
        # ...
```

However, in the name of testability etc., I'd avoid using global variables and maybe just encapsulate your state into a class.